# How do I install my apk on the phone without running it?

Tags: android, eclipse

Here's some brief background on my question; maybe the real answer is to just change my approach.

I have an application that can run all by itself, but certain activities can be called using intents from outside the application.  Lately, I've been using a little test app I built to try this out, and any time I change the code in my main application, I have to run it, close it, then run the test app.

Not too big a deal, really.  Still, I'm curious to find out if there's a way to just install new code without having the app launch on the phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By invoking `adb install YourApplication.apk` from the command line.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like the best way to do it.  I completely failed to mention that I'm developing on Eclipse; when working in that environment, I often forget to use useful command line tools!  For the benefit of others who are, like me, far too dependent on IDEs, does anybody know if there is an equivalent to "adb install" inside Eclipse?  I searched around but came up blank.

Answer (score 0):

Also any file browser (try ASTRO from the market) will let you select the APK file on your sdcard/storage and install it from within your phone.